# WatchKit How set a string when a certain table is pressed?(Swift)

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

Im creating a watch app but i have a problem and that is that i want to set a string depending on which table the person pressed in the watch app.

Can anyone help me?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're trying to perform an action when a user taps on a WKInterfaceTable row?

You can achieve this using table:didSelectRowAtIndex: by identifying the corresponding string based on the index and sending an appropriate message to the string.

See the [WKInterfaceTable Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/table:didSelectRowAtIndex:)